# Class & method inheritance in c++

Tags: c++

So, I thought I get it, but I don't... This is my header file `shapes.h`:

```
#ifndef __shapes__
#define __shapes__

class Shape {

public:
    double h;
    double w;

    virtual double area(void);

    virtual void rotate(void);
};

class Rectangle : public Shape {
public:
    Rectangle(double h, double w);

    double area(void);

    void rotate(void);

private:
    double h;
    double w;
};

#endif
```

and then I implement it in `shapes.cpp` as:

```
#include "shapes.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

/*
 * Rectangle methods
 */
Rectangle::Rectangle(double height, double width) {
    this->h = height;
    this->w = width;
}

double Rectangle::area() {
    return this->h * this->w;
}

void Rectangle::rotate() {
    double temp = this->h;

    this->h = this->w;
    this->w = temp;
}
```

And in my `main.cpp` I do:

```
#include <vector>
#include "shapes.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void){

    vector<Shape *> shapes;

    Rectangle u(2,5);
    shapes.push_back(&u);
    Rectangle v(3, 4);
    shapes.push_back(&v);

    double area = 0;
    for(Shape * p : shapes){
        area += p->area();
    }
    ...
```

And I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "typeinfo for Shape", referenced from:
      typeinfo for Rectangle in shapes-12a86a.o
  "vtable for Shape", referenced from:
      Shape::Shape() in shapes-12a86a.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
```

I assumed that the error speaks for itself and looked up for similar questions, to which I found a lot answers, but could not figure out the mistake in my code...

Comment: You do not need `(void)`

Comment: `"Undefined symbols ..."` and `"Shape::parameter()"` are pretty good hints (although they apply to real code, not what you posted here.)

Comment: @juanchopanza I am not sure I understand.

Comment: Definition for virtual double area(void), virtual void rotate(void); in shape class is missing.. or you can make shape functions area and rotate as pure virtual

Comment: @juanchopanza I posted just part of my code, so I don't have too big of a post and after your comment I noticed a typo in the code and updated it, along with my question.

Comment: This isn’t the problem, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__shapes__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `Shape::area` and `Shape::rotate` but you did not define them

One solution would be to change shapes.h like this:

```
class Shape {
public:
    double h;
    double w;

    virtual double area(void) { return 0; }
    virtual void rotate(void) {}
};
```

Another solution is to instead add the definitions to shapes.cpp:

```
double Shape::area() { return 0; }
void Shape::rotate() {}
```

As juanchopanza pointed out, another solution is to make the methods pure virtual (which is probably best):

```
class Shape {
public:
    double h;
    double w;

    virtual double area(void) = 0;
    virtual void rotate(void) = 0;
};
```

Comment: Probably `double h` and `double w` should not be public nor a part of shape

Comment: @EdHeal, Probably not but that is not the error he is experiencing

Comment: Probably not a great idea to provide dummy definitions. Declaring the functions as pure virtual might be better.

Comment: I did the definitions in `shapes.cpp` but I don't see that as a very nice solution, since it doesn't add any functionality. And I am still getting this error: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

Comment: @Milkncookiez, That probably means you did not compile main.cpp and shapes.cpp together. I compiled them like this: `g++ main.cpp shapes.cpp`. It is not a matter of adding functionality, it is a matter of making your code link-able